# Tag badges suggestion

Tags: feature-request, tagging, badges

I want to ask whether there are tags which shouldn't have badges attached. For example I have a bronze badge for the "soft question" tag. Now my preference would be to keep tag badges on the site to fields or aspects of mathematics rather than qualitative features of questions.

There aren't many to which this would apply, and I appreciate this would take a change for potentially relatively little effect - by the time you get such a badge you generally have a wide range of credentials on the site. But philosophically it seems wrong to me. What do you think?

Comment: Arguably those tags should not exist to begin with. I think this is actually a good litmus-test if something should be a tag.